# grabbing hevc h265 stream using ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, hevc, h.265

I have a problem when I try to grab h265 encoded video from ip camera using rtsp protocol.
I want to save stream from camera and i use `https://github.com/sahilchaddha/node-rtsp-recorder/` to do this. Almost all works perfectly but output video has green bars and I don't know why.

These are my parameters

```
ChildProcess {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _closesNeeded: 1,
  _closesGot: 0,
  connected: false,
  signalCode: null,
  exitCode: null,
  killed: false,
  spawnfile: 'ffmpeg',
  _handle: Process {
    onexit: [Function],
    pid: 96408,
    [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular]
  },
  spawnargs: [
    'ffmpeg',
    '-i',
    'rtsp://[...]',
    '-vcodec',
    'copy',
    'videos/cam1/Aug-26th-21/video/2021-8-26-5-51-13.mp4'
  ],
  pid: 96408,
  stdin: null,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null,
  stdio: [ null, null, null ],
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

and result
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OWUO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try to use `ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i [...]`

By default ffmpeg uses udp as the rtsp_transport.